# How do I use getch from curses without clearing the screen?

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm learning to program in C and want to be able to type characters into the terminal while my code is running without pressing <kbd>return</kbd>. My program works, however when I call `initscr()`, the screen is cleared - even after calling `filter()`. The documentation for `filter` suggests it should disable clearing - however this is not the case for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>

int main(void) {

    int ch;

    filter();
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    while((ch = getch()) != EOF);

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the above code still clearr the screen, and what could be done to fix it?

I'm using Debian Lenny (stable) and gnome-terminal if that helps.

Comment: For PDCurses you can set the environment variables PDC_PRESERVE_SCREEN or PDC_RESTORE_SCREEN to any value: from the file HISTORY:

Comment: PDC_PRESERVE_SCREEN
 If this environment variable is set, PDCurses will not clear the screen
 to the default white on black on startup.  This allows you to overlay
 a window over the top of the existing screen background.

 PDC_RESTORE_SCREEN
 If this environment variable is set, PDCurses will take a copy of the
 contents of the screen at the time that PDCurses is started; initscr(),
 and when endwin() is called, the screen will be restored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `newterm()` instead of `initscr()`, you should be fine then. And don't forget about `delscreen()` if you follow this advice.

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I have tried what you said and the functionality is the same - the screen was cleared again. In place of `initscr()` I have `FILE *fild_id = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+"); SCREEN *termref = newterm(NULL, file_id, file_id);` and instead of `endwin()` I have `delscreen(termref)`.

Comment: Strange but it doesn't clear my screen when I use it instead of `initscr()`. I call it as `newterm(NULL, stdin, stdout)` though.

Comment: The only reason it's not clearing your screen, Mike, is that you reversed the arguments to newterm(). It takes stdout, stdin, not stdin, stdout. I bet after your test program runs, your input is messed up? Doesn't echo, perhaps? If you use the correct argument order for newterm() it does indeed clear the screen. Your answer is just wrong.

Comment: Why not delete this answer?

Comment: I'm all for it but I cannot seem to delete the answer while it's accepted @TedLyngmo. Any assistance on it is welcome.

Comment: @mike.dld I see.  I now remember that happening to me too. Well, that answers that question. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You would see your screen cleared in a curses application for one of these reasons:

- your program calls [`initscr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-initscr) (which clears the screen) or [`newterm`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-newterm) without first calling [`filter`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_util.3x.html#h3-filter_nofilter), or
- the terminal initialization clears the screen (or makes it appear to clear, by switching to the alternate screen).

In the latter case, you can suppress the alternate screen feature in ncurses by resetting the `enter_ca_mode` and `exit_ca_mode` pointers to NULL [as done in `dialog`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/dialog-snapshots/blob/master/util.c#L387).  Better yet, choose a terminal description which does what you want.

Further reading:

- [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite) (xterm FAQ)

Answer (score 2):

Extending the answer by mike.dld, this works for me on MacOS X 10.6.6 (GCC 4.5.2) with the system curses library - without clearing the screen.  I added the ability to record the characters typed (logged to a file "x"), and the ability to type <kbd>CONTROL-D</kbd> and stop the program rather than forcing the user to interrupt.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>

#define CONTROL(x)  ((x) & 0x1F)

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("x", "w");
    if (fp == 0)
        return(-1);
    SCREEN *s = newterm(NULL, stdin, stdout);
    if (s == 0)
        return(-1);
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    int ch;
    while ((ch = getch()) != EOF && ch != CONTROL('d'))
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", ch);

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does clear the screen for me (so it does not work).

Comment: @nh2: it might depend on your terminal type and the curses entry that you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, curses is designed to take over the screen (or window, in the case of a windowed terminal). You can't really mix curses with stdio, and you can't really use curses to just input or output something without messing with the rest of the screen. There are partial workarounds, but you're never really going to be able to make it work the way that it sounds like you want to. Sorry.

I'd suggest either rewriting your program to use curses throughout, or investigating alternatives like readline.