# how to go back to normal mode after closed the curses window

Tags: c, curses

Here is my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char str[120];
    char c;
    while (1) {
        printf("%s", ">");
        scanf("%s", str);
        if (!strcmp(str, "open")) {
            initscr();
            c=getch();
            endwin();
            printf("from curses window %c\n",c);
        }
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have a `while(1)` loop that always prints whatever it gets from screen.

If you input "open", it will open a curses window, and get a `char`. After that it will exit the curses window (`endwin()`), and should still be in the `while(1)` loop.

But my problem is that after calling `endwin()` it won't go back to the normal `printf()/scanf()` loop.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772061/curses-library-c-getch-without-clearing-screen

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char str[120];
    char c;
    FILE *file_id;
    while (1) {
        printf("%s", ">");
        scanf("%s", str);
        if (!strcmp(str, "open")) {
            file_id = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+");
            SCREEN *termref = newterm(NULL, file_id, file_id);
            //cbreak();
            echo();
            keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
            getstr(str);
            delscreen(termref);
            printf("from curses window %s\n", str);
        }
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

now the source code upgrade to this, and still have two problem

1, after open and close the term once, it can back to the normal loop, but when I press enter, the promt will not align on the left side, it will be like this,

```
user@linux>
           user@linux>
                      user@linux>
```

2, i can type in "open" again , to open a new term again , but the new term is still in the same localtion as the term created when i inputted the "open" in the first time, 
actually , everytime i input open , a term will be created at the same place , that means the command behind first open will disapear.