# box function gives no output for newwin

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm running ncurses on c4droid on Android. Here, `box()` works perfectly with window pointer of `initscr()` but no box of `newwin()`.

Code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    WINDOW * Win = initscr();
    noecho();
    crmode();
    WINDOW * win = newwin(10, 10, 1, 1);
    box(Win,0,0); // This works
    box(win,0,0); // no output
    wrefresh(win);
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `refresh()` refreshes the *main screen*, which will clear your window. But if you remove it it still does not work. It is because `getch()` acts upon the main window and implicitly refreshes it. So the fix is to

1. place `refresh();` **before** `wrefresh(win);`
2. [change `getch()` to `wgetch(win)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748685/curses-library-why-does-getch-clear-my-screen)

Answer (score 0):

The `refresh` call overwrites the `wrefresh`, since the `initscr` call tells the curses library to initialize the screen before it does anything else, and because that initialization is applied to `stdscr`.

Changing the order would help (but also, reading from the most recent window to update helps more):

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    WINDOW * Win = initscr();
    noecho();
    crmode();

    WINDOW * win = newwin(10, 10, 1, 1);
    box(Win,0,0);
    refresh();

    box(win,0,0);
    wrefresh(win);

    wgetch(win);
    endwin();
}
```