# What is the difference between wgetch() and getch() in ncurses?

Tags: ncurses, getch

I have looked and I can't seem to find this mentioned anywhere.

Comment: `wgetch()` expect a `WINDOW` reference/pointer, `getch()` does not. Check the parameter lists of these function.

Comment: @Progman This doesn't answer the question. What's the purpose of this parameter?

Comment: Most likely to reference a `WINDOW` instance from the ncurses library. Check https://code.woboq.org/linux/include/curses.h.html#WINDOW for its definition and the documentation of the available ncurse functions which work with `WINDOW` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getch()` is equivalent to `wgetch(stdscr)`. The function `wgetch` does `wrefresh` of the specified window and then reads input. So `getch()` would refresh `stdscr` and then wait for input.

more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22121866/515212